# how to call a php class function directly using ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to call a php class function DIRECTLY using ajax?

Something like below... except ajax...

```
myclass::myfunction();
```

I've been using the jquery library to work with AJAX.

```
$.get('control.php', {func: funcName, arg1: arg1});
```

The above is similar to what I'm trying to achieve MINUS the control.php;

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but I just thought it would be nice to skip the landing page (control.php) that recieves the funcName. I have a bunch of conditional statements that sort out what class function to run based on the funcName recieved.

It seems kind of silly to do this, to have a separate page just to handle function calls.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

If this were possible, it would be a gaping security hole.

Comment: Hrm, I don't understand. Can you explain why...? Give example. Thanks

Comment: @payling: Do you really want any javascript page able to call `exec()` directly? That's an example, but there are plenty of dangerous functions (and some of your functions probably aren't safe to be called like that either).

Comment: @payling if there was a way to invoke _any_ method directly that way, one could simply (manually) construct a call that will perform just that. This way, anyone (with or without permission) could perform the logic inside that method (which is probably not a very good idea.)

Comment: Imagine what would happen if you could write `$.ajax({func: 'unlink', path: 'C:\\Windows' })`.

Comment: Hrm, I guess calling php built in functions may be a problem...

I guess I was only considering the script would call only functions that I've made.. ;)

Comment: Are you *sure* that all of your functions are safe to call with any arguments?

Comment: Well no, I'm not sure if my arguments are "truly" safe. 

I use the filter_input(input_get,'name',filter_sanitize_string) to sanitize my input.

Comment: @payling I don't think SLaks meant that sort of safety. You can sanitize your data all you want, the kind of exploit we're talking about here exceeds all that. Imagine you have `function promote($user_id) { mysql_query("UPDATE Users SET is_admin=true WHERE user_id=$user_id"); }` you don't really want just about anyone calling this function now do you ;)

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't invoke a method directly that way.

You could use routing (like the technique used in CodeIgniter and CakePHP) but that's just syntactic sugar that does the same thing -- control your routes to actions.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible because of a simple reason. How should the AJAX knows, where to find the function. It needs to have a URL to locate the function so it doesn't work without a php file in between.

Answer (score 0):

No for security reasons but there is no reason why you can't do something like this

```
function run($args){
  //do stuff
}

echo run($_REQUEST);
//or
echo run($REQUEST['name']);
```