# How to submit the ID of input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible (and if so, how) to submit the ID of the input field in focus when clicking it?
I've made an autosave-feature in a online-tool, that saves every time an input field is blurred.

However, since the page itself is updated on every field blur, it loses focus when another field is clicked, so I would like it to submit the ID of the field, just clicked so that I can set it in focus, manually.

(off-topic) I don't use jQuery anymore when updating, since I need the page to process a lot of numbers, serverside... so in my opinion, it's most convenient that it works as described.

I've done some researching and ended up with two possibilities:

```
focusobject = $(':focus');
```

and

```
document.activeElement
```

but when doing a JS alert, it just says [object Object] and [object HTMLBodyElement] instead of "fieldEmail"

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I previously used this to update in the background:

```
function writeNow(datastring) {
    $.ajax( {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'update.php',
        data: datastring, 
        success: function(data) {
            // Do nothing       
            }
    });
}
```

This updates the fields just fine on onBlur, but the page itself calculates a lot of results, based on several class methods on runtime. If I use AJAX to update the database values, I don't see how I can set the class variables and display the correct result without reloading.

Comment: You could declare a variable and store the last focused element in it. On submit, submit this variable, it'll have the last focus'd element.

Comment: I'd be tempted to use a hidden field.  Add code to set the value of whatever field has focus.  Though you may have to account for someone clicking the submit button.

Comment: Yes, that was the intention, but I never get a field ID. Instead, it tries to pass an object, like "[object Object]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on an element, it's more likely that it will get focus (unless there is some wizardry that prevents the click from requesting the focus). You may simply handle the `onclick` event of an input group and save it.

Let imagine some input fields that all have classname `txt-group-1`:

**Plain JS**

```
var lastFocus = null;
if (document.activeElement.className == 'txt-group-1') {
    lastFocus = document.activeElement.id; // get the field that already has focus
}

var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('txt-group-1');
for (var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('click', function(evt){
        alert(this.id+' has focus!');
        lastFocus = this.id;
    },true);
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var lastFocus = null;
if (document.activeElement.className == 'txt-group-1') {
    lastFocus = document.activeElement.id; // get the field that already has focus
}

$('.txt-group-1').click(function(evt){
    alert(this.id+' has focus!');
    lastFocus = this.id;
});
```

Then, `lastFocus` will always have the ID of the last element that had focus so you can put it back if needed.

---

**UPDATE:**

**in case of a CMS that needs to save the fields:**

Your best friend in that situation will be [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). The idea is to be able to save the new value in database without having to refresh the whole page, hence stopping any action that goes after.

I suggest that you take a look at the method that saves the fields and optimize it in a way that it doesn't need to refresh the page:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "save.php",
  data: {inputFieldName:'txtEmail', inputFieldValue:'foobar@mail.com'}
})
.done(function(data) {
  console.log('saved'); // after the request is complete
});
```

Any post-save client-side action may be specified in the `.done` event. It's also possible to get a response from the server-side script that execute your request.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I've tried the jQuery-code and technically, it works as intended, but there's a catch...

Comment: The system consists of several input fields, so that when you click one, it autosaves the content of the previously active field.

All fields has a jQuery focus and a blur - and I hoped that my variable "currentActiveField" would be set BEFORE the blur-code which updates and then refreshes the page, is executed.

This way, we have 3 vars; currentActiveField, blurField, blurFieldValue and we can update the database with the blurField-vars and at the same time, transfer the new ID

Comment: @Anders - The click (onclick) should happen before it loses focus (onblur), `lastFocus` in that case holds the previously focused element rather than the new one. Before the blur event triggers a page refresh, the last focused element should already be known. If you want to get the element that *WILL* get the focus, this is not possible if the blur event refreshes the page.

Comment: @Anders Maybe easier to use an ajax request to prevent refreshing the page ?

Comment: Ah, of course - I'll try a different approach, then :) The problem is exactly as you describe in the end of your reply.

Comment: I previously used AJAX in order to prevent the page from refreshing itself and that worked out alright. However, the page consists of a lot of classes/instances that do a lot of calculation on every refresh, so I then put the calculation part in Javascript, but that turned out to be much too cumbersome to handle in the long run

Comment: @Anders - Please take a look at my last update, there should not be a situation in which it is too *difficult* to achieve, only cases that need to be optimized in order to be more simple.

Comment: sorry for the delay; I just became father and had to reprioritize for a few days. Anyway, your update outlines pretty much the way it used to work until recently. The only thing is that if the page itself doesn't refresh, the calculation which is based on the input fields doesn't change since this is done, serverside in a class method. And since you can't call a member method according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999895/how-to-call-a-php-class-function-directly-using-ajax I dont see how I can update a calculation, even if I use jQuery/AJAX

Comment: @Anders Congratulation and good luck! As for the refresh problem, everything that is executed at the beginning could be into another ajax call isn't it? Let data_refresh.php be the server-side script that refresh everything. That file may be called in an ajax request and bound to your class :-)

Comment: Well yes and no, I've got 2 files; one called "instance.php" and "update.php", which is called through AJAX. "Instance" runs through a database and finds out, which calculation modules (classes) to instantiate. The calculation formulas reside inside each class as a public method and all relevant classes are executed when instance.php is loaded. If I understand you correctly, I should let update.php update the content of the placeholder-divs that contains the results? Is that possible? I mean, for a second file to access the content of the caller?

Comment: Or do you want me to make instance.php call itself using AJAX? I tried and moved the updating-code inside instance.php. The data are written in the databse, but since the page loads in background, it never displays the new, calculated values. Another solution could be to make jQuery grab the formula from the classes on pageload and then calculate the variables, based on the input fields, rather on the database content. That approach is unfortunately pretty cumbersome, since I'll have to pass along the identity of an unknown number of input fields...

Comment: @Anders Sorry but I can't assist you in your project as SO still remains a Q&A forum. The shorter question is the better. If your question needs further information to be answered correctly, please provide that information directly in the question. Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<input name="testfield" type="text" id="mtTextField" onClick="alertId(this.id);">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function alertId(getid)
    {
        alert(getid);   
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Try out this code.

Comment: Hello Harsha. Thank you for your answer. However, it's a bit more complicated than that. There are a lot of input fields, each with its own id and name. Each input has a blur and a focus, so that when a user clicks another field, it updates (not using AJAX, please se my comment to Frederik). So: (1) User clicks new field, its ID should be set in a variable (2) Which field did the user leave? Update the value of that field in the database and transfer the ID of the new, active field to itself (3) Set focus on the new field after page load

Answer (score 0):

Use's Harsha's snippet except hang it on the "onchange", otherwise you will create an issue with tab navigation. You will have to modify your save function slightly so it won't trigger with every character.
Also instead of updating the entire page I suggest using AJAX.

Comment: I'm not sure if AJAX will help here. I've previously built a submit-function in AJAX but I still need to refresh the page in order to update a bunch of serverside values. The most convenient way is to just let the page call itself. I'll comment on Harsha's code in a moment and explain further...